# Delegated approver not able to approve

Tags: approval-process

I have a delegated approver who has `Modify All` access to an object, the object has OWD of `Public Read/Write` but when the approver tries to approve, I get an error saying Insufficient Privileges. Am I supposed to enable anything else?

Comment: do any of the approval actions involve something the delegated approver doesn't have access to?

Comment: All I'm doing is change the record type and update a field. As I said, the User has 'Modify All' object-level permission

Answer (score 0):

Users with one of these permissions can approve or reject pending approval requests without being part of the approval process.

- Modify All” object-level permission for the given object
- Modify All Data” user permission

You can provide access **Modify All Data” user permission** and check if it is working.

Comment: `Modify All Data` is a dangerous permission to give to non sysads